# how to execute command after current running command in bash?

Tags: linux, bash

I'm downloading file with wget, and I want to turn off my computer after downloading will be finished, but I need to go somewhere now :) Is it possible to execute command in bash exacly when process will be finished?

I know that this works:

```
wget http://example.com/file.rar; shutdown now
```

But what if I type only:

```
wget http://example.com/file.rar
```

Comment: Consider using && and || instead of ;.  && and || check the return value of the previous command before executing the next command...just in case wget fails, you may not want to shutdown.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can do something like this:

1. Suspend execution of wget with `ctrl-z` (it's not stopped, it's suspended)
2. Put it into background with `bg`
3. Run: `wait; shutdown -h now`

`wait` will wait for all programs running in background in the current shell - i.e. this wget to finish. After *wait* finishes - *shutdown* will run.

Comment: don't forget to foreground (fg) your wget instance when done.  If wget is already running, you can put it into the foreground with ^z (control-z).

Comment: No need unless you really want to see the progress bar.

Comment: No need since he is leaving the machine to itself and then shut down.

Answer (score 11):

In another shell, use

```
ps -u <your username> | grep wget
```

to find the PID of the command you want to wait on, then

```
wait <PID>; shutdown -h now
```

so that shutdown will not run until process  has terminated. See also [depesz's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/35179/how-to-execute-command-after-current-running-command-in-bash/35190#35190).

Comment: +1, just a note: `wait` will only work for commands started from the same shell

Answer (score 6):

My solutions is this: suspend your long-running task with Control+Z, then type something like:

```
fg; echo "Done!"
```

If you want to run react differently based on the success or failure of your command, use && and || as short-circuit operators.

```
fg && echo "Success!" || echo "Failure!"
```

EDIT: This won't work with sudo, because it will ask for your password. I have, accordingly, removed the examples using sudo. If you need sudo for the second task, use another of the methods posted here.

On the other hand, I believe that both GNOME and KDE offer ways to trigger a shutdown/reboot without using sudo, by sending an appropriate D-Bus signal or something.

Comment: +1 for `fg`..., but `sudo` could be a problem if it prompts you for a password

Comment: Hmm. Yes, I haven't used this trick for sudoing things when something finishes. For sudo, you'd need a different trick. I'll edit my post accordingly.

Comment: For my purpose this answer is superior as it puts the process automatically back into the foreground

Comment: Also, passwords for sudo can be disabled (per user and per command) - if the user is allowed to shutdown via sudo this once, he might be allowed to do so always. A hostile shutdown might not be that dangerous in some cases - certainly not as dangerous as a compromised guest access on a running machine.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just type out your second command and press enter. If your current program is scrolling text you can't see what you're typing correctly so watch your keys so you do it right.

A smarter way is to switch to another TTY (CTRL+ALT+F1 through F6) and run the command simultaneously, or if you're using a command-line program like screen you could create a new window in it.

Comment: +1 for the first option. I'm afraid I don't understand how the second option is supposed to work.

Comment: Pressing for example CTRL+ALT+F2 will switch you to a new second console where you can login and type a command, in this way you can run a second command there. Second, if you download screen (a program to use your console in a more fancy way) you can open up a second tab/window where you can again type commands, without having to login again. But as you need it simultaneously, you can stay with option 1, I don't think there is another way to achieve the same effect. Unless you use another TTY/window to check through a script if the process is still running. :-P

Comment: Use the wait PID from dmckee's answer

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get fancy, check the return status of the wget and only shutdown if it was successful.

```
% wget http://example.com/file.rar
% if [ $? -eq 0 ]
> then
> shutdown now
> fi
```

Comment: This is a good approach when scripting, but while `wget` runs you don't get a prompt back to build the test.

Comment: You can combine this with my Control-Z and fg trick to get around that.